# Creating Relationships in Cypher Between Nodes with Shared properties with values that are 1 and 1.0

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have properties on two different node types. The properties are 1 and 1.0. I want to connect these nodes with a relationship based on this shared property. There are about 45 million nodes to connect to another 1.2 million nodes. I generated the following query to do this but it keeps returning `(no changes, no records)`. Does anyone know the best way to go about doing this? Query is below.

MATCH (p:Post),(t:Thread) 
WHERE EXISTS (p.post_reply_number) AND EXISTS (t.pos) AND p.post_reply_number=t.pos CREATE (p)-[r:FIRST_POST]->(t)

Comment: what are the data types of p.post_reply_number and t.pos? int and double or string and double?

Comment: You don't need the `EXISTS` terms, since the equality test would not succeed if one or both properties do not exist anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the data types are not consistent. One of the properties is string and the other one is double(float).  You can use the function toFloat to convert string to float then your query will work.

```
MATCH (p:Post),(t:Thread) 
WHERE EXISTS (p.post_reply_number) 
 AND EXISTS (t.pos) 
 AND toFloat(p.post_reply_number)=t.pos 
CREATE (p)-[r:FIRST_POST]->(t)
```

I tried creating sample nodes/properties using the data types int(post_reply_number) and float (pos) and your query works.